# Thread unable to join in tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am building a GUI and encounter a problem of not enable to join a thread properly. I extracted the essential part and wrote the following code: A button to start a thread and a button to close a thread.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
from time import sleep

class test:
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry('300x100')
        self.runAllflag = False
        tk.Button(root, text="run", command = self.run).pack()
        tk.Button(root, text="stop", command = self.stop).pack()
        self.status = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Label(root, textvariable = self.status).pack()
        root.mainloop()

    def test1(self):
        while self.runAllflag:
            sleep(0.1)
            print('threading runnning')
        else:
            print('Escaped from the loop') 
            self.status.set('Stopped')  #### Seems that the program stuck here ###
            print('Status written "Stopped')

    def run(self):
        if not self.runAllflag:
            self.runAllflag = True
            self.status.set('Running')
            self.t = threading.Thread(target=self.test1)
            self.t.start()

    def stop(self):
        if self.runAllflag:
            self.runAllflag = False
            self.t.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

When I run the GUI, click the run button and then the stop button. Here's is message log:

```
threading runnning
threading runnning
threading runnning
threading runnning
threading runnning
threading runnning
threading runnning
threading runnning
threading runnning
threading runnning
threading runnning
threading runnning
threading runnning
threading runnning
Escaped from the loop
```

It seems that the program is stuck at the line to write write the label content in the function `.test1(self)`. I wonder what is the reason that it cannot write it properly.

Comment: `.join()` is blocking, remove it you don't need it.

Comment: @stovfl, thank you for the help! I wonder why `.join()` will cause a problem